# Capture 1-9 after the last occurrence of 0

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to capture all numbers between 1 and 9 after the last occurrence of zero except zero in the last digit. I tried this pattern it seems that it doesn’t work.

`Pattern: [1-9].*`

DATA

```
0100179835
3000766774
1500396843
1500028408
1508408637
3105230262
3005228061
3105228407
3105228940
0900000000
2100000000
0800000000
1000000001
2200000001
0800000001
1300000001
1000000002
2200000002
0800000002
1300000002
1000000003
2200000003
0800000003
1300000003
1000000004
2200000004
0800000004
1300000004
1000000005
2200000005
0800000005
1300000005
1000000006
2300000006
0800000006
0900000006
1000000007
2300000007
0900000007
0800000007
1000000008
2300000008
0900000008
0800000008
1100000009
2300000009
0900000009
0800000009
1000005217
2000000429
1100000020
1000005000
3000000070
2000000400
1000020000
3000200000
2906000000
```

Desired Result

```
179835
766774
396843
28408
8408637
5230262
5228061
5228407
5228940
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
5
5
5
5
6
6
6
6
7
7
7
7
8
8
8
8
9
9
9
9
5217
429
20
5000
70
400
20000
200000
6000000
```

Comment: Try `(?:^0*[1-9]+0*\K0|0\K(?:[1-9]+(?:0[1-9]*)?|[1-9]0*))$` https://regex101.com/r/GC1I3w/1v

Answer (score 1):

You can anchor the end of the string and match non-zero digits with an optional trailing zero. Ensure that there is at least one matching digit with a positive lookahead pattern:

```
(?=\d)[1-9]*0?$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/uggV37/2

Answer (score 1):

To get desired result:

```
(?:^0*[1-9]+0*\K0|0\K[1-9]+(?:0[1-9]*|0+)?)$
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `^` Start of string
  - `0*[1-9]+0*` Match 1+ digits 1-9 between optional zeroes
  - `\K0` Forget what is matched so far and then match a zero
  - `|` Or
  - `0\K` Match a zero and forget what is matched so far
  - `[1-9]+` Match 1+ digits 1-9
  - `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

    - `0[1-9]*` Match a zero and optional digits 1-9
    - `|` Or
    - `0+` Match 1+ zeroes
  - `)?`  Close the non capture group
- `)` Close the non capture gruop
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sBUKvA/1).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Match 1 item each line:

```
'0123056'.match(/(?<=0)[1-9]*0?$/g).filter(m => m != '')
```

Match multiple item each line:

```
'0123056 0000210 1205000 1204566 0123456 0012340 0123400'.match(/(?<=0)[1-9]*0?\b/g).filter(m => m != '')
```